# Android - Get current webview for setWebViewClient()

Tags: android, webview

After times of searching, I could not find the result for this:
My browser application is using webview, I need to use this function: currentwebview.setWebViewClient(). But I do not know how to get the current webview to apply that function.

I mean when I do not have the current webview id, then is there a way to get current webview for using setWebViewClient() ??

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

findViewById same as you would any view.

WebView currentWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_web_viewId);

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not making myself clear, what I meant was that when I don't have my current webview id, then how can I get that current webview ? (I have changed my question for a clear understanding)